# Detect overlapping time ranges in PHP

Tags: php

[image]

I want to see if time ranges overlap, if they do, true should be returned, otherwise false. If I have selected this time range:

> **10:30:00 - 11:30:00**

then I need to check if it doesn't overlap another time range. For example:

> **10:30:00 - 11:30:00** overlaps with **10:30:00 - 12:30:00** so I have to disable the slot but I don't know how to do the comparison correctly.

I have the following function, but I think it doesn't work as I want it to work.

```
  $as = $selectedSlot['slot_start'];
  $ae = $selectedSlot['slot_end'];
  $bs = $DB_slots['slot_start'];
  $be = $DB_slots['slot_end'];


function checkSlotRange($as,$ae,$bs,$be){
  $as = strtotime($as);
  $ae = strtotime($ae);
  $bs = strtotime($bs);
  $be = strtotime($be);
  if($as <= $bs && $ae <= $be){
    return true;
  }else{
  return false;
  }  
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You had the time checking logic wrong. You need to check that A's start time is later than B's start time, AND A's end time is earlier than B's end time.

```
<?php
function checkSlotRange($as,$ae,$bs,$be){
    $as = strtotime($as);
    $ae = strtotime($ae);
    $bs = strtotime($bs);
    $be = strtotime($be);
    return ($as >= $bs && $ae <= $be); 
}
var_dump(checkSlotRange("10:30", "11:30", "09:30", "12:30")); // true
var_dump(checkSlotRange("10:30", "11:30", "11:40", "12:30")); // false
```

[Demo](https://3v4l.org/3P3OD)

I don't know if your time ranges go over midnight, but if they do, you need to add the day to the timestamp to do the comparison, otherwise you'll get unexpected results.

Comment: i need to check $as-$ae comes withing $bs-$be or not

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand you. Is the example not working for you? Or it's not what you want?

Comment: I see, what did you need instead? 10:30 - 11:30 intersects with 09:30-12:30 so it's `true`, 10:30-11:30 doesn't intersect with 11:40-12:30, so it's `false`. How should it be?

Comment: i just want to compare 1 Time range comes under another time range  if yes then function will return true if no then false

Comment: Ohhh do you mean completely contain it? Like 10:30-11:30 and 11:20-12:30 should be `false`?

Comment: yes absolutely because  10:30-11:30 is in the range of 11:20-12:30

Comment: Glad I could help!